# help downloading Ubuntu to older laptop

Tags: system-installation, downloads

I am trying to download Ubuntu to an older laptop with windows on it from Ubuntu's website. I am new at Ubuntu and need some help. I tried watching some YouTube videos, but I get a completely different layout when I am trying to install it compared to the videos. Please help me asap! Thank you

Comment: what do you download and what you saw on youtube?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link for the official download page for Ubuntu: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

But, you did mention that you had an old laptop so I would recommend Lubuntu: http://lubuntu.net/

If you are on Windows 7 or above, right-click on the Ubuntu .iso file and select "Burn to Disk". A window will pop up and will allow you to burn Ubuntu to the disk. If you are using Windows Vista and below, you are going to have install and 3rd party DVD burner. When the DVD is done burning, reboot your laptop, press F8 or F12 to open the boot menu and then select the dvd to boot from it. After a few minutes, the Ubuntu setup will appear and you will be able to install Ubuntu from there. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use USB flash drive to install Ubuntu. Here is the installation help http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop.

You create Ubuntu USB drive by using Unetbootin program; download the LTS ISO, then launch Unetbootin, select 'Diskimage' and start. When finished, you must restart and go into BIOS and set boot priority of USB drive to first. Then when you boot from USB, you should first 'Try Ubuntu' to make sure all the necessary hardware works with it (sound card, network, wireless network if you have one, bluetooth...). If all is OK, install it.